# images in jar file won't show up

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, embedded-resource

So my trouble is that when I put this game into a .JAR file it won't show up.  I can still see the bullets but I can't see the invader images

```
public class Invaders {
protected int xPos;
protected int yPos; 
protected int moveStep = 0;  
protected int size = 15; 


static BufferedImage invader1image = DrawingPanel.loadBitmap("invader1.jpg");
static BufferedImage invader2image = DrawingPanel.loadBitmap("invader2.jpg");

//some code in the middle omitted


public void draw(Graphics g, int seconds) {

    if(seconds%50 < 25){
    g.drawImage(invader1image, 
            this.xPos-this.size, this.yPos-this.size,
            this.size*2, this.size*2,null);
    } else{ g.drawImage(invader2image, // this isn't working
            this.xPos-this.size, this.yPos-this.size,
            this.size*2, this.size*2,null);

    }
}
```

Comment: What does loadBitmap look like?

Answer (score 3):

you should get the images the following way

```
BufferedImage invader1image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("invader1.jpg"));
```

now you keep your images along your class file